# Commerce - How do I add the purchaser of a specific product to a user group?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want all buyers of a specific product to automatically be added to a specific user group.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a business logic plugin if you haven't already.

Two good ways of doing that are : [Business Logic Plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) or via http://pluginfactory.io

Then, in your plugin's main file in the `init` method, register a listener method:

```
public function init()
{      
    craft()->on('commerce_variants.onOrderVariant', 
        [
            craft()->businessLogic_logic,
            "onOrderVariantHandler"
        ]
    );
}
```

Then, implement the method (I do this in my class BusinessLogic_Logic Service):

```
public function onOrderVariantHandler($event){

    $variant = $event->params['variant'];
    if ($variant->product->id == "4194" ){
        $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
        craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [3]);
    }

}
```

Obviously make sure you use the right `id`s for your particular products & groups!

Note you can also just implement the method directly in `init()` if you want to keep things very simple - but the above method makes for a cleaner main plugin file and once you start doing a lot of this sort of thing (which is where a lot of the real power of Commerce lies I think) - separating the logic into a service and just registering the handlers is a more ordered way to go I think.

```
craft()->on('commerce_variants.onOrderVariant', function($event){
    $variant = $event->params['variant'];
    if ($variant->product->id == "4194" ){
        $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
        craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [3]);
    }
});
```